# Get all "Accept" headers from Flask

Tags: python, flask

A client sends multiple Accept headers to my Flask app. However, `request.headers('accept')` return only the last set header. How can I see all values for the Accept header so that I can serve the latest version of my API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.headers` is a [`MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), which provides the [`getlist`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) method to get all the values for a given key.

```
request.headers.getlist('accept')
```

The default `Request` class [parses accept headers](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.AcceptMixin) into more useful forms.  Since you specifically care about the accept headers, use these attributes instead.

```
if request.accept_mimetypes.accept_json:
    ...
```